# VirtualHosts on AWS EC2 is not working

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I want to set multiple website hosting on one EC2 instance.Both domain directing to one IP address
I configured /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file as-

```
#NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain2"
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    <Directory "/var/www/domain2">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all Granted
    </Directory>
#    RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is Server only directing to domain1.com
When I put domain2.com in URL it shows me apache default page "Amazon Linux AMI Test Page"

And reason I commented NameVirtualHost * is- after restarting httpd service, I get

**Starting httpd: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:355**

What else setting should I do? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Does the IP address for both of your domains point to the same IP (that of our EC2 instance)?  Have you tried to access the site using incognito mode in your browser (eliminates a possible browser cache issue)?

Comment: You called the server "doamin" in the VH config, but refer to "domain" in the url. Possibly just a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Lots of Trial and error; Finally It works.. :)

I changed to following code in httpd.conf file-

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName alivefruits.com
    ServerAlias www.alivefruits.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName revealautomation.com
    ServerAlias www.revealautomation.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/reveal"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/reveal">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your virtual host configuration is missing a port.  Instead of

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

try

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...I Already tried it... It doesn't work either.